# Error trying to add item to selectlistitem in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewmodel, selectlist, selectlistitem

I have a select list defined in my model

```
public class VM_modal
{
    [Key]
    public int VM_modalID { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> SearchOptions  { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I am trying to add items to this list, but I am getting an error saying the arguments are invalid.

```
var vm_modal = new VM_modal();
vm_modal.SearchOptions.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" });
```

As far as I can see I'm doing it the same way as shown in this example http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and few others that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on your code, the SearchOptions property is not initialized, so it will reference to null at run-time. Try instantiating your list before adding an item to it.

Comment: Ah I figured out the problem, it was that I was using System.Web.Mvc namespace in my model, but System.Web.WebPages.Html in my controller for the select lists. I'm just using mvc in both now.